# Java JDBC issue, Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am using Java JDBC to connect to a MySQL database and load data in to a table. the Load in data statement works fine when it is run from a GUI interface (I am using Navicat). But it doesn't work when I take that same statement and place it in a text file which then I read using the following code:

```
public String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) throws IOException {
    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
    return encoding.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(encoded)).toString();
}

String hcccontent = readFile("resources/loadinhcc.txt", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);                
String[] loadinhcc = hcccontent.split(regex);
for(int i = 0; i < loadinhcc.length; i++){
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.execute(loadinhcc[i]);
}
```

This works fine as I even stepped through the code extracted the query my Java program parsed, copied it into navicat and it Loaded all the data. When I run it and let the program try to execute, I get the following error "Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns"

I have searched online and the closest thing I have seen  that could be causing this issue is MySQL strict mode. where MySQL doesn't load if the input is longer than what is specified in the tables, or maybe wont load if there isn't data for all columns. But it doesn't make sense this would be causing this problem exactly since the query works in Navicat. Is there a setting in JDBC to disable strict mode? Or is it something else I am missing?

Comment: What does `loadinhcc[i]` contain?

Comment: its the load in statement that wont work on the program but works fine when i run it from navicat. The actual query is:

LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/test.txt'  INTO TABLE hcc 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ignore 1 lines;

Comment: You can't use 'sqlldr` commands to load data via JDBC. You have to use SQL .. `insert into table (col1, col2,...) values ( val1, val2..);`

Comment: I was able to load this same way into another table from another text file with the load data infile... This one is breaking because it seems like there isnt data for one of the columns.. Which normally when I run in Navicat it will leave null.. but it seems JDBC is not liking it or something..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a session is started through a JDBC connection, MySQL is set to strict. I tested my query on the command line and through the GUI and both times the query worked. It was only when running the query through JDBC that I got back an error. According to Timothy on MySQL bug forums:

> A possible workaround is to turn off strict mode, either for the whole
>   server, for a particular session, or for just a few statements. For
>   example:
>
> set @old_sql_mode = @@sql_mode; set sql_mode = ''; 
>   -- Run some statements which may result in data truncation set sql_mode = @old_sql_mode;

I executed the `set sql_mode= ''` before the running any queries, and the errors stopped.

```
 stmt.execute("SET sql_mode = ''");

 for (int i = 0; i < loadinhcc.length; i++) {

      stmt.execute(loadinhcc[i]);
 }
```

**Additional information**

[MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html)